# "Academic Careers in Statistics" vs "Statistics Careers in Academia"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, differences, syntactic-analysis

I am working on a report for survey results about academic opportunities for Statisticians i.e. Careers for Statisticians at Academic Institutions. I understand any of the following titles should work, but I am curious if one of them is *more accurate over the other*. Or if one of them doesn't convey the right meaning.

1. Academic Careers in Statistics
2. Statistics Careers in Academia
3. Academic Careers for Statisticians

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

*Academic Careers in Statistics* points to academic careers **within** (in the sense of *restricted to*) the study of statistics, statistical careers of an academic nature, a description that ignores the possibility of a non-statistical part to the career - such as statistician's rising to the position of university principal, where their statistical skills are no longer explicitly required.

*Statistics Careers in Academia* points to statistical careers **within** (in the sense of *as part of*) academia, the careers being placed within a wider academic context. As above, wider academic roles are ignored.

*Academic Careers for Statisticians* points to an academic career suitable for statisticians. It leaves open all possibilities: that the academic career will involve the study of statistics; and that academia also offers other opportunities for statisticians.

From this analysis I prefer the last as the most flexible title.